# Setting a default value in the selectfield, using wtforms and flask

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am creating a product edit form and I need the form to be pre-populated with the previous data.

I am doing the following:

```
Product(form):
    product = TextField('name')
    category = SelectField('category', choice=[(1,'one'),(2,'two')])
```

In the view:

```
form.product.data = 'A product name from the database'
form.category.data = 'a category name' #This does not work
```

The issue is with the SelectField.

I understand there is a 'default' value I can set on SelectField. However, this happens in the form definition class and there I do not have the query object from sqlalchemy yet.

So, is there a way to append a default on selectfield on run time?

Comment: `form.category.data = 1` or `form.category.data = 2`

Comment: I tried. Not working.

Comment: It's as falsetru says, but before set coerce as int:  `category = SelectField('category', choice=[(1,'one'),(2,'two')], coerce=int)`. form is the Product Form instance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want set default value to render page with form you can create own form or set value:

```
class Product(Form):
    product = TextField('name')
    category = SelectField('category', choices=[(1,'one'),(2,'two')])

# create instance with predefined value:
form1 = Product(category=2)
# form1.product == <input id="product" name="product" type="text" value="">
# form1.category == <select id="category" name="category">
#                     <option value="1">one</option>
#                     <option selected value="2">two</option>
#                   </select>
# from1.product.data == None
# form1.category.data == 2

# create own form if it need many times:
Product2 = type('Product2', (Product,), {
    'category': SelectField('category', default=2, choices=[(1,'one'),(2,'two')])
})
form2 = Product2()
# form2.product == <input id="product" name="product" type="text" value="">
# form2.category == <select id="category" name="category">
#                     <option value="1">one</option>
#                     <option selected value="2">two</option>
#                   </select>
# from2.product.data == None
# form2.category.data == 2
```

If you want set default form data on request:

```
with app.test_request_context(method='POST'):
    form = Product(request.form)
    # form5.category.data == None

    form = Product(request.form, category=2)
    # form5.category.data == 2

with app.test_request_context(method='POST', data={'category': 1}):
    form = Product(request.form)
    # form5.category.data == 1

    form = Product(request.form, category=2)
    # form5.category.data == 1
```

Comment: How about `QuerySelectField`, can we do it..?

Answer (score 12):

From the WTForms documentation

> Note that the choices keyword is only evaluated once, so if you want to make a dynamic drop-down list, you’ll want to assign the choices list to the field after instantiation.

```
Product(form):
    product = TextField('name')
    category = SelectField('category')
```

And then in your view say

```
form.category.choices = [list of choices with chosen data]
```

More detail found here:
http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField

Comment: How about `QuerySelectField`, can we do it..?